# How can I override the Equals method for object with DateTime fields or properties

Tags: c#, unit-testing, assert, equals-operator

I am writing test unit for a method that returns an object. I create an expected object and compare it

```
    public class Model
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Editor { get; set; }
        public DateTime Edited { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            var myObj = obj as Model;
            if (myObj == null)
                return false;
            return myObj.Id == Id &&
                myObj.Editor == Editor &&
                myObj.Edited == Edited;
        }
    }
```

```
    public void MyTest()
    {
        Model expected = new() { Id = 1, Editor = "Me"};
        Model result = cut.getModel();
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, result);
    }
```

Equals compares Id and Editor but it is always false for the Edited property.

How can I compare instances of this object? Should I Ignore DateTimes fields and properties in the Equals method?

First proposal:

```
    public void MySecondTest()
    {
        Model expected = new() { Id = 1, Editor = "Me"};
        Model result = cut.getModel();
        expected.Edited = result.Edited = Now;
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, result);
    }
```

Comment: Well you're defaulting `Edited` to the current system local time. We don't really know what you're trying to do, so we can't tell you how `Model.Equals` *should* behave. Do you *want* it to compare the `Edited` times? How are you expecting to use the equality comparison?

Comment: some nice video from Nick about how to target problem with DateTime You're facing https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5DrGdyxnO5A&t=416s

Comment: "but it is always false for the Edited property" is verifyable false: `(new Model { Edited = DateTime.Now.Date}).Equals(new Model { Edited = DateTime.Now.Date})` returns true.

Comment: I want to compare two objects but Edited is always different. Equals method should compare every field and is always false. How can I change Equals to ignore Edited?

Comment: `How can I change Equals to ignore Edited?` Remove `&& myObj.Edited == Edited`

Comment: @AlbertoMartín "Edited is always different" is false, similarly to your statement in the post (see my comment above)

Comment: Also note that if you override Equals, you shouldalso override GetHashCode - and make it consistent with Equals.

Comment: Calling `DateTime.Now` on two different line of code have different values at the milliseconds level. That's why they are not the same. If the real data does not deal with the milliseconds, you should change the comparison logic to limit the comparison to Date, hour, minute and seconds. (removing seconds also would make more sense).

Comment: @Chetan, If I remove the comparison for Edited not all properties are taken into account. Is it a good practice?

Comment: What are you actually trying to test with this unit test?

Comment: What's your requirement of comparing two objects and deciding if they are the same? Is `Edited` property necessary to be compared while comparing for the equality? How you compare the DateTime value is also matters. As I mentioned in the earlier comment, you can limit the comparison of DateTime value to only Date, Hour and Minute if that satisfies your need.

Comment: @Evk I trying to test the result of GetModel(). It should return the expected object. My question is about the Equals method and the best way to write it.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov "Is always false" unless you set both values in the same line as you did

Comment: "It should return the expected object" - what is expected object? It returns something with the same Id and Editor, but different Edited, is that expected?

Comment: @Evk The expected object is the first parameter for Assert.AreEqual statement. Two objects created in different moments have different Edited, but the other fields are equals. So, I should change this field in both objects to pass the assert. See my next suggestion.

Comment: "So, I should change this field in both objects to pass the assert" - maybe, maybe not. It's unclear, because (again) we really don't know what the requirements are. It's like me asking you whether I should get a 3m network cable or a 10m network cable...

Comment: @JonSkeet The requirement for GetModel() is getting a Model with an specific Id and Editor.

Comment: @AlbertoMartín: Does `GetModel` use `Equals`? What *in your production code* uses model equality? If nothing does, you should probably not be overriding `Equals` at all. Just perform assertions on the ID and Editor in your test.

Comment: @JonSkeet Not at all. The comparison is only to perform unit testing. In my code example, the Class only has a few properties. In my production code this class is huge and I should check the properties one by one or use reflection ignorig Editing

Comment: If you don't need the code for production purposes, I wouldn't add it in there. Do only what you need for test purposes - and I'd suggest only checking the properties you actually need to check, too.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is with the "Edited" property that is assigned to "DateTime.Now" which is a different value everytime you create an object. Try assigning an exact value:

```
public class Model
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Editor { get; set; }
    public DateTime Edited { get; set; } = new DateTime(2022,10,28,16,0,0);

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var myObj = obj as Model;
        if (myObj == null)
            return false;
        return myObj.Id == Id &&
            myObj.Editor == Editor &&
            myObj.Edited == Edited;
    }
}
```

Now if you do:

```
Model model1 = new Model() { Id = 1, Editor = "editor1" };
Model model2 = new Model() { Id = 1, Editor = "editor1"};

model1.Equals(model2) //should be true
```

Comment: I cannot modify the default value, but I can modify Edited for both instances before the .Equals

Comment: yes, it's either one or the other